# .htaccess RewriteRule to target WordPress category

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a site in **root** folder which has its own .htaccess file. There is also a WordPress installed in a separate **wordpress** folder with its own .htaccess. I'm trying to target WordPress category directly from the main site but with the prettier URL. I want when I type

```
mydomain.com/blog/
```

to take me to the

```
mydomain.com/wordpress/category/blog/
```

I have tried to put rewrite rule to the .htaccess file in the main site, like this

```
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ wordpress/category/blog/
```

but it breaks and show error "*The requested URL /blog/ was not found on this server.*". It seems that the second .htaccess file in wordpress folder or something else breaks it.

Comment: This won't work with Wordpress since it relies on REQUEST_URI and that remains original `/blog/`. However if you have mod_proxy installed then a solution might be possible.

Comment: Hmm, I posted an answer that should work around it, but come to think of it I believe that the REQUEST_URI actually gets updated when using a rewriterule.

Comment: Sorry, I had to delete my answer. I can't figure out a working way to do this.

Comment: I can access some test file that I create inside wordpress folder, for example wordpress/test.php. But when I try to target some wordpress structured link, it doesn't work. I've even tried to change both .htaccess files but without success.

Comment: As I commented above, only way it will work with `mod_proxy` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible (as has been pointed out in the comments) unless you redirect the browser to the full Wordpress URL:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ wordpress/category/blog/ [L,R=301]
```

The only other way to get this working is to change the Wordpress PHP files yourself to handle this specific kind of redirect.